# build docker container from command line (windows)

Tags: windows, docker, build, containers

I'd like to build a docker container from command line only - on windows.

On Linux it works like this:

```
docker build -t tcpdump - <<EOF 
FROM ubuntu 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y <packages here>
EOF
```

Any ideas how to port it to windows?

Comment: Make that sense?
It's better to use Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use this.

```
ECHO "FROM python:3
RUN pip install requests" | docker build -t yourimage:tag -
```

Please take a look at this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/commandline/build/#text-files) as well.